# GEE Python API Map Visualization not working

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, mapping, api, geemap

I am working in Google Collaboratory and the Google Earth Engine Python API Map will not show. It was all working as of 7/6 5pm EST and then 7/7 at 10am it stopped rendering. I have attached my code below. When calling the "Map" variable, the Map will not show.

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1BCY3w_frL5OTYymTG2gobbUmLtWQBmbZ

Code:

```
import geemap as gee
import ee

Map = gee.Map()
Map
```

Comment: I had the same issue, solved by using Folium.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running through anaconda (or mini), I fixed this by going to the command and installing both plotly and folium (I don't think you need both, but both packages are helpful for mapping)

(base) C:\Users\blahblah>pip install folium

and then

(base) C:\Users\blahblah>pip install plotly==5.15.0

Restarted my notebook and it was fine.

**REMINDER**: It wont work if you try to install through Juypter. Has to be through the command window.